# Connecting a Bluetooth Device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

```
package com.example.stef.bluetooth_version1000;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT=1;
   private  ArrayList<String> devices;
   private List<BluetoothDevice> list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Handler handler=null;

        /*Creation des objets Bluetooth*/
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        final Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
            devices.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress());
        }

        final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devices);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        final BluetoothChatService bluetoothChatService= new BluetoothChatService(MainActivity.this,handler);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                bluetoothChatService.start();
                bluetoothChatService.connect();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

My function connect needs a BluetoothDevice parameter.
I would like to be able to get it from the ListView onClick(), but I only managed to get a name or an address.

It seems that I need to get the Bluetooth device from the Set "Paired Device".
I am using the `ConnectionChatService.java` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a raw adapter that's only reading strings

Actually store a list of BluetoothDevice [in a custom adapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

Start with a custom class

```
public class BluetoothArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {
    // implement getView
```

Then you can use it , for example, in the click listener to get the item at the clicked position

```
final BluetoothArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new BluetoothArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.your_bluetooth_layout);
arrayAdapter.addAll(mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices());
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            bluetoothChatService.start();
            bluetoothChatService.connect(arrayAdapter.getItem(i));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ! 
Now im trying to use a BluetoothClass, i read a lot of documentation and tutorial but it is not clear at all.
There are a lot of ways to do it .

Comment: As far as I know, there's only one way to communicate with a BluetoothSocket

Comment: I followed these steps :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
And i don't know how to interact with my bluetoothService in my MainActivity

Comment: My recommendation would be to try using the sample app https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html